# I have some problems with VectorAssets

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

When I add "android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true." for my Vector Asset to Gradle, those problems pop up. Please someone tell me how to fix this.

Those are the errors: 
ERROR: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.testInstrumentationRunner() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner]

org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.viewassets"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true.
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: You have a dot after `true`. So you're trying to call a method `testInstrumentationRunner()` on the Boolean `true`. Hence the error message.

Comment: You should remove the trailing dot here `android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true.`

Comment: ok I made it. Thanks a lot